# why is calibration of my logistic regression s shaped?

Tags: probability, logistic, calibration

I am simulating data to compare real and predicted probabilities from logistic regression like this:

```
set.seed(2)
library(simstudy)
def <- defData(varname = "x1", dist = "uniform", formula="0.01;0.99")
def <- defData(def, varname='x1.small', dist='nonrandom', formula='x1<0.15')
def <- defData(def, varname='biomarker', dist='binary', 
               formula='x1.small/2', link='log')
def <- defData(def, varname='real_risk', dist='nonrandom', 
               formula='x1 + biomarker/4')
def <- defData(def, varname = "y", dist = "binary", 
               formula='x1 + biomarker/4', link='identity')
data <- genData(1000, def)
test_data <-genData(200, def)

predictions <- predict(glm(y ~ x1 + biomarker, data=data, 
                           family='binomial'), test_data, type='response')
plot(predictions, test_data$real_risk, xlab='predicted_probability', 
     ylab='real_probability')
```

however when I plot real vs. predicted probabilities, the relationship is not linear, but S-shaped. I think I assume linearity somewhere where I shouldn't. Why is this relationship s-shaped, and how can I get data where it is linear?

[image]

Comment: Don't compare probabilities: compare log odds (the logistic of the probabilities).  That's the whole point of the `type` argument to the `predict` function!

Comment: so I should compare real probabilities to log odds of predicted probabilities? This is linear, but how can I get something on a same scale?

Comment: No, you should compare log odds to log odds.  BTW, because your question relies on details of what the user-written function `defData` does, it's not comprehensible: could you at least explain what that function is intended to do?

Comment: But wouldn't you still want samples with predicted probability of 0.4 have the predicted target outcome 40 percent of times? Also, what's the difference between log odds vs log odds or probabilities cs probabilities? If one is linear shouldn't the other be linear as well?

Comment: The defdata function comes from lybrary simstudy that should help to simulate data. I create some input variables which are then used to create a random outcome variable according to the relationship specified in formula and link keywords

Answer (score 1):

I was simulating my data incorrectly. The identity link is not creating the data according to assumptions of logistic regression, although I can't tell what is going on exactly in that library. The correct thing to use is logit link but instead of raw probabilities, give it log odds of your probabilities like this:

```
def <- defData(varname = "x1", dist = "uniform", formula="-5;5")
def <- defData(def, varname = "y", dist = "binary",
           formula='x1', link='logit')
```

Then to plot the calibration on probability scale and not log odds, simply let glm predict probability and transform your log odds using logistic like this:

```
predictions1 <- predict(glm(y ~ x1, data=data, family = 'binomial'),
                        test_data, type='response')
plot(predictions1, logistic(test_data$x1)); abline(0,1)
```

[image]

but I am curious why is the `link='identity'` misbehaving, but documentation seems to be terse in this aspect